# Constructing a star-shaped polytope from its kernel

Tags: convex-geometry, computational-geometry

Suppose $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ form the vertices of a convex, bounded polytope $P$ with positive volume. I have two questions:

1. is there a largest star polytope ($S$, say) with kernel equal to $P$?
2. If so, are there algorithms for constructing the vertices of $S$?

I actually have a conjecture: the answer is yes for Q1, and regarding Q2, $S$ can be obtained as follows. $P$ satisfies $P=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^d: Ax\le b\}$ for some $k\times d$ matrix $A$ and some $b\in\mathbb{R}^d$. ``$\le$'' should be understood component-wise here. Then, letting $A_{-j}$ denote the submatrix of $A$ with row $j$ removed (and similarly for $b_{-j}$), $S$ satisfies $$S=\cup_{j=1}^k \{x: A_{-j} x\leq b_{-j}\}.$$
Is that right?

**Edit**: some simulations suggest that the conjecture could be correct for $d=2$. However, the corresponding algorithm I have used is quite inefficient because it requires (i) a facet enumeration to obtain $A$ and $b$; (ii) $k$ vertex enumerations to obtain the vertices of $\{x: A_{-j} x\leq b_{-j}\}$ for $j=1…k$. Also, this construction does not seem to work for $d>2$.

Comment: Why should the union of all polytopes with kernel equal to $P$ be a polytope?

Comment: @5xum: you are right, this is not obvious, let me edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @lhf: I also added a condition to avoid that degenerate case.

Comment: What is the solution for $d=2$ and $|P|=3$ ?

Comment: @lhf: you mean $n=3$? In this case it is whole plane, if I am not mistaken. In this case the points of the corresponding polytope would be at infinity. I don't mind about that.

Comment: Ok, I was considering $S$ to be a bounded polytope, discarding the whole plane.